# How to allows forced MFA when users connect to an specifis app

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication, fortigate

I configured my vpn ssl on fortigate to authenticate with Azure AD.
I create an conditional access to required MFA.
But when user try to connect some days after the application don’t ask for login passWord or MFA.

I want to force every connexion of this application to require MFA.

Can you help me please.

I try to reduce sign in frequency to one hour but it don’t work

Answer (score 0):

> How to allows forced MFA when users connect to an specifis app.html

I have created sample web application with `Azure Ad Authentication`.

[image]

**Azure Identity**

[image]

You can add below code in your application configuration to force the login screen for every login.

**Web Config file**

```html
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="HomePage.aspx"
    loginUrl="UnAuthorized.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30">
          </forms>
</authentication>
```

**Startup.Cs**

```html
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender,AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
     if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
        {
            Login1.Visible = true;
            Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
        }
     else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid Login");
        }
    }
```

You can achieve this by creating a custom `Conditional Access policy` to require `MFA` for the specific application.

**Portal Configuration:**

[image]

And configure the sign-in frequency in the `Conditional Access policy` to require `MFA` for every connection.

**Login Page:**
[image]

Reference: [Preventing Open Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks)